# WSO2 API Manager 1.6.0: register server via REST does not work

Tags: api, rest, curl, wso2, publish

What is wrong with my request to register a service? I can not get it working.

Login (ok)

```
curl -k -s -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -X POST https://my.server.com/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'
```

Register/Publish service, fails

```
curl -k -s -c cookies.txt -b cookies.txt -X POST https://my.server.com/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag -d 'action=addAPI&name=GetLand&context=GetLand&version=1.0&tier=Unlimited&transports=http&http_checked=http&transports=https&https_checked=https&description=Dummy Description&visibility=public%20API&tags=Mondriaan&resourceCount=0&resourceMethod-0=GET,POST&resourceMethodAuthType-0=None&uriTemplate=/*&resourceMethodThrottlingTier-0=Unlimited&tiersCollection=Unlimited' -d 'endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":">http://mgm-fon-web.nl.rsg/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/SOAP_TEST_GET_LAND","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}'
```

I get only the folling error:

```
{"error" : true, "message" : " null"}
```

And in the log:

```
 ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-add.ajax.add:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.site.blocks.item-add.ajax.add:jag}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make urlencoded data for the post parameters. This may improve your problem.

Also, `>http:` from your parameter may hurt you as well. In my windows after the `>` sign its expecting to have a valid file name. Not sure how it reacts on linux or mac. So once again, try to post the urlencoded data.

Comment: curl -k -s -b cookies.txt -X POST http://my.server.com:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag -d 'action%3DaddAPI%26name%3DGetLand%26context%3DGetLand%26version%3D1.0%26tier%3DUnlimited%26transports%3Dhttp%26http_checked%3Dhttp%26transports%3Dhttps%26https_checked%3Dhttps%26description%3DDummy%20Description%26visibility%3Dpublic%2520API%26tags%3DMondriaan%26resourceCount%3D0%26resourceMethod-0%3DGET%2CPOST%26resourceMethodAuthType-0%3DNone%26uriTemplate%3D%2F*%26resourceMethodThrottlingTier-0%3DUnlimited%26tiersCollection%3DUnlimited'

Comment: -d 'endpoint_config%3D%7B%22production_endpoints%22%3A%7B%22url%22%3A%22%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fother.server.com%2Forawsv%2FSNL_OWNER%2FSOAP_TEST_GET_LAND%22%2C%22config%22%3Anull%7D%2C%22endpoint_type%22%3A%22http%22%7D'

Comment: {"error" : true, "message" : "timeout"}
Any thoughts?

Comment: lol, you've encoded all the values. In a parameter there have two parts, key and value. In your case just do the urlencode over the value only. Let say this portion `action=addAPI&name=GetLand`. Here you need to do urlencode over `addAPI` and `GetLand`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo mistake in my URL; apart of the ">", I did not set the correct values of the method and made a typo-mistake in the attribute name. I hop ethe next release, WSO2 AM should show a syntax error when a non-existing parameter is passed.